# Q: Setting up RAID1 on CentOS, running into an error

Tags: centos, raid, raid1

I'm quite new to linux / setting up RAID and was tasked with setting up RAID1 on CentOS system. I've found myself stuck, without much luck from google.

I've tried creating the RAID1 device thru the following command and received this error:

```
[root@itc160 itc]# mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=mirror--raid-devices=2 /dev/sda2 /dev/sdb1
mdadm: super1.x cannot open /dev/sda2: Device or resource busy
mdadm: ddf: Cannot use /dev/sda2: Device or resource busy  
mdadm: Cannot use /dev/sda2: It is busy
mdadm: cannot open /dev/sda2: Device or resource busy
```

my fdisk-l log looks like this:

```
[root@itc160 itc]# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 250.1 GB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0000e7e0

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048     2099199     1048576   83  Linux
/dev/sda2         2099200   123344895    60622848   8e  Linux LVM
/dev/sda3       123344896   488397167   182526136   fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/sdb: 250.1 GB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x7ce03322

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048   488397167   244197560   fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/mapper/centos-root: 53.7 GB, 53687091200 bytes, 104857600 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/centos-swap: 8384 MB, 8384413696 bytes, 16375808 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

Did I go wrong with partitioning, or is there something making my device busy?

EDIT*

Tried unmounting as suggested, to no avail.

```
[root@itc160 itc]# umount /dev/sda2
umount: /dev/sda2: not mounted
```

Comment: The error is telling you that /dev/sda2 is busy. Unmount it with `umount /dev/sda2`

Comment: I've tried. It tells me sda2 is not mounted and the error persists.

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't set it up as part of the OS installation via the installer? It looks like raid is already setup with /dev/sda3 and /dev/sdb1

Comment: The machine was already given to me in installed state, I just gave in and reinstall the OS while setting up RAID in the installer now

Answer (score 0):

/dev/sda2 is identified as '8e Linux LVM'. The most probably it is part of some volume group (VG). Try to list physical volumes (PV) used by the LVM on your server:

```
pvs
```

If it's really used in some VG, you'll have to either remove the VG or remove the PV /dev/sda2 from the VG. Be carefull!

If it's not really used as physical volume, change the type of the partition to the 'fd  Linux raid autodetect'.

Comment: I've gathered this from the pvs `/dev/sda2  centos lvm2 a--  57.81g 4.00m ` does that mean this machine wasnt properly partitioned? And will I have to reinstall the OS?

Comment: It depends what you mean with properly installed. On the /dev/sda1 (/boot I guess) you have just 1 GB and the /dev/sda2 is used for VG called centos, which serves for your Linux filesystem. So you'll require /dev/sda2 for that anyway. However you can shrink it. You have /dev/sda3, which you may use instead of the /dev/sda2. For your RAID1 setup, you should use partitions of the same size, otherwise only size of the smaller one will be effectively used. The best, use sda3 and sdb1 and shrink the size of the sdb1 to the size of sda3, so you can use the rest of /dev/sdb for something.

Comment: I've shrunk sdb1 size and tried with sda3 and sdb1, however I was getting message that it cannot find sda3 directory. So I've just reinstalled OS and configured raid in the installer, as I have already lost too much time with this matter, thanks for your help.